# Access View inside WEB-INF using angular.js

Tags: spring

I am new to AngularJS. In my project all views html are inside WEB-INF folder, I want to use AngularJS so I have written app.js and controller.js but view is not rendering.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put them in WEB-INF. By design, WEB-INF is inaccessible from the outside. You can put your templates anywhere you want, except WEB-INF.

Or, since you're apparently using Spring, [configure it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) to serve those resources, instead of using the default servlet.